On pushouts and the topology of adjunction space
A couple of weeks ago I had my first contact with CW-complexes through Dieck's Algebraic Topology book. Currently, I'm also reading from other books like Hatcher's and Prasolov's.
I really don't know if this is a dumb question, but after reading Proposition A.1 (p. 520) in Hatcher's book I got myself thinking if, given a pushout in $\mathrm{Top}$ like the one below (Notation: $Z\approx X\cup_{\varphi} Y$), the space $Z$ has the topology coinduced by the maps $X\to Z$ and $Y\to Z$. I haven't been able to produce a counterexample.
$$
\begin{array}{c}
   A    & \xrightarrow{\subseteq}  &    X     \\
 \downarrow{\varphi} &         &  \downarrow{\Phi}  \\
   Y    & \xrightarrow{\subseteq} &    Z     \\
\end{array}
$$
Any ideias on how to prove or disprove this "claim"?

Hint: Use the universal property of the coinduced topology. ...or a general description of co/limits in $\mathrm{Top}$.

How do you define the adjunction space $Z$? The way I would do it, it pretty much follows from definition.

I have removed the non-suitable tags.

Consider a pushut diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> X \\
@V{g}VV @VV{G}V \\
Y @>{F}>> Z
\end{CD}
We shall prove that the topology $\mathfrak T_Z$ of $Z$ is the final (or coninduced) topology with respect to $F,G$.
One could do it by looking at the explicit construction of the pushout, but let us give a proof using the universal property of the pushout.
The final topology $\mathfrak T_{fin}$ is the finest topology on the set $Z$ such that the functions $F, G$ become continuous. Clearly $\mathfrak T_{fin}$ is finer than $\mathfrak T_Z$. Let $Z_{fin}$ be the underlying set of $Z$ endowed with $\mathfrak T_{fin}$. Since $F : Y \to Z_{fin}$ and $G : X \to Z_{fin}$  are continuous and
$$G \circ f = F \circ g ,\tag{1}$$
the universal property of the pushout yields a unique continuous $\phi : Z \to  Z_{fin}$  such that
$$\phi \circ G = G \text{ and }  \phi \circ F = F . \tag{2}$$
Since $id : Z_{fin} \to Z$ is continuous, we see that $\phi = id \circ \phi : Z \to Z$ is continuous. By $(1)$ it is the unique continuous map satisfying $(2)$. But $id : Z \to Z$ has this property, thus $\phi = id$. This shows that $\mathfrak T_Z$ is finer than $\mathfrak T_{fin}$.

Thanks! I managed to prove it using the hint given above by Ben Steffan, but your solution is way better and clearer.

Hint. Open subsets correspond to the continuous maps to the Sierpinski space. And continuous maps on a pushout are understood via the universal property. Hence, you can derive the topology from the universal property (of any colimit of topological spaces).
